# RAID 1+0 on Windows 7 Professional after installation

Tags: windows-7, raid

I have an old PC running Windows 7 Professional unformatted since 2008 on a GA-Z77X-UD3H motherboard presently which according to the instructions has support for RAID 1+0.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it working via the hardware route.

My desktop has 4 x 2TBs that are presently out of warranty and I want to set it up as a RAID 1+0.  For one they're slow so I want the striping and they're old and may die at anytime so I want mirroring.

Anyway, I was wondering how to configure the drives if it is even possible Windows 7 Professional with Disk Manager or diskpart.

I am not booting from the RAID drives.  I am still booting from an old 1.5TB basic disk.  The 2TBs are extra for data only that I want to RAID.

Comment: You won't be able to boot from software RAID volume. To boot from RAIDed array you'll have to set up so called fake RAID, that is the feature provided by your MoBo. Or you can go for real hardware RAID, but you'll need a (very) expensive controller to configure it (basically everything below $300 is probably just fake RAID, ie. software RAID assisted by firmware to allow booting).

Comment: I updated the configuration details.  I am not booting from RAID drive.

Comment: AFAIR you have to delete all partitions first and you'll be able to set up RAID 0 or RAID 1 in Disk Management. I'm not sure if RAID 10 is possible, though.

Comment: Yup that's right I can set up 0 or 1 but not 1+0 at least not that I can tell.

Comment: Using RAID 10 with 4 hard drives means you have 2 usable drives worth of storage.  See if RAID 6 is an option it offers a better level of protect, but could be easier to find.  In RAID 10 if disk 0 fails in mirror A and mirror B all is lost.  Same disk 1 fails on both sets.  In RAID 6 **any** 2 drives can fail and you can still rebuild.

Comment: Thanks I'll be happy with RAID 10 which is minimal.  RAID 5 or 6 aren't even available from what I can tell.